# Jackson catch unrecognized field in a map

Tags: java, jersey, jackson

I'm using Jackson in a java Rest Api to handle request params.

My Bean class :

```
public class ZoneModifBeanParam extends ModifBeanParam<Zone> {
@FormParam("type")
private String type;

@FormParam("geometry")
private Geometry geometry;

@FormParam("name")
private String name;

...
```

My API interface :

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json; subtype=geojson")
@ApiOperation(value = "Create a zone", notes = "To create a zone")
public Response createZone(ZoneModifBeanParam zoneParam) {

...
```

This Works fine but I need to receive other params that aren't specified by my Bean in a Map.
Example :

```
{
   "geometry": {...},
   "name": "A circle name",
   "type": "4",
   "hello": true
}
```

By receiving this I need to store in a Map (named unrecognizedFields and declared in my bean) the couple ("hello", true).

Is there any annotation or object allowing this?

Comment: You may be able to ignore the unrecognized fields safely by configuring the `ObjectMapper`, however to specifically put them as key-value pairs of a `Map` field, you'll need your own de-serializer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use [@JsonAnySetter](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_458.html). That's what it's made for. Here is a test case

```
public class JacksonTest {

    public static class Bean {
        private String name;
        public String getName() { return this.name; }
        public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

        private Map<String, Object> unrecognizedFields = new HashMap<>();

        @JsonAnyGetter
        public Map<String, Object> getUnrecognizedFields() {
            return this.unrecognizedFields;
        }

        @JsonAnySetter
        public void setUnrecognizedFields(String key, Object value) {
            this.unrecognizedFields.put(key, value);
        }
    }

    private final String json
            = "{\"name\":\"paul\",\"age\":600,\"nickname\":\"peeskillet\"}";
    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Test
    public void testDeserialization() throws Exception {
        final Bean bean = mapper.readValue(json, Bean.class);
        final Map<String, Object> unrecognizedFields = bean.getUnrecognizedFields();

        assertEquals("paul", bean.getName());
        assertEquals(600, unrecognizedFields.get("age"));
        assertEquals("peeskillet", unrecognizedFields.get("nickname"));
    }
}
```

The `@JsonAnyGetter` is used on the serialization side. When you serialize the bean, you will not see the `unrecognizedFields` in the JSON. Instead all the properties in the map will be serialized as top level properties in the JSON.

Comment: It's perfectly what I was looking for! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to ignore the unrecognized fields safely by configuring the ObjectMapper, however to specifically put them as key-value pairs of a Map field, you'll need your own de-serializer.

Here's a (heavily simplified) example:

**Given your POJO...**

```
@JsonDeserialize(using=MyDeserializer.class)
class Foo {
    // no encapsulation for simplicity
    public String name;
    public int value;
    public Map<Object, Object> unrecognized;
}
```

**... and your custom de-serializer...**

```
class MyDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Foo> {
    @Override
    public Foo deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // new return object
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        // setting unrecognized container
        Map<Object, Object> unrecognized = new HashMap<>();
        foo.unrecognized = unrecognized;
        // initializing parsing from root node
        JsonNode node = p.getCodec().readTree(p);
        // iterating node fields
        Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> it = node.fields();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, JsonNode> child = it.next();
            // assigning known fields
            switch (child.getKey()) {
                case "name": {
                    foo.name = child.getValue().asText();
                    break;
                }
                case "value": {
                    foo.value = child.getValue().asInt();
                    break;
                }
                // assigning unknown fields to map
                default: {
                    foo.unrecognized.put(child.getKey(), child.getValue());
                }
            }

        }
        return foo;
    }
}
```

**Then, somewhere...**

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
Foo foo = om.readValue("{\"name\":\"foo\",\"value\":42,\"blah\":true}", Foo.class);
System.out.println(foo.unrecognized);
```

**Output**

```
{blah=true}
```

Comment: Your solution works fine, I tested it! But peeskillet solution is more compatible with my Forms annotations. Thanks for your help