# Include a list of name value pairs in Jackson object dynamically

Tags: jackson, jersey

In my response object, I can easily add a map that Jackson will serialise e.g.

```
public class Response {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    Map map = ...

}
```

The JSON will be

```
{
    "firstName": "tony",
    "lastName": "lastName",
    "map": {}
}
```

But say I don't want the word map and I want to dynamically add name value pairs so they are at the same level as firstName and lastName, how do I do that?  Really don't want to extend Map.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44296725/2587435 Maybe this is what you're looking for

Comment: If I understand well the question, all the keys-values in the map should appear at the same level as fields (no map in the serialization) ?